# How to prepare storebought hopia

Tags: asian-cuisine

I bought a pack of pork hopia from the store. Pre-made. How do I prepare it? Goldilocks brand. I don’t remember if it was frozen or refrigerated.

There don’t appear to be any hints on the package or the manufacturer’s website.

They look similar to the pastry pictured on the [Wikipedia article here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bakpia).

In the words of Mr. Malone, “This is a new food for me.” My guess is to maybe throw one in the toaster oven and cross my fingers.

Comment: The pastries described are pre-made, but are they also pre-cooked? Is the dough set, or soft? Without more information, you may indeed be better off just tossing one in the toaster oven for about 20 minutes at 375.

Comment: @Onyz I wasn’t totally sure when I asked yesterday, which is why I wasn’t specific. After some experimentation today, I can confirm they are cooked.